# Why are identical contents zipping to non-identical archives, even with `-X`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, zip

So, let's create two identical (empty) files. We'll have to put them in different directories, since otherwise they couldn't coexist with the same filename:

```
$ mkdir a b
$ touch a/1
$ touch b/1
```

*(Note: don't do `$ touch a/1 b/1` in a single command, since then the file creation timestamps might be identical and this experiment won't work)*

We can confirm these files are identical:

```
$ md5sum a/1 b/1
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  a/1
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  b/1
```

Now I'm going to zip each of these two files into their own archive. I'm going to pass the `-X` flag to `zip`, which causes it to ignore file attributes like the creation/modification time, which should be the only difference between these two files. Note that I run `zip` within each subdirectory so that the relative path is identical as well.

```
$ cd a && zip -X ../a.zip 1 && cd -
$ cd b && zip -X ../b.zip 1 && cd -
```

I would expect `a.zip` and `b.zip` to be exactly identical, but strangely:

```
$ md5sum a.zip b.zip
9dedfd0e992695d002c65992452e921c  a.zip
49079421fec66cf71969024a06cfd69a  b.zip
```

If I diff the hex dumps of the zip files, I end up with

```
$ xxd a.zip > a.bin && xxd b.zip > b.bin && diff a.bin b.bin
1c1
< 00000000: 504b 0304 0a00 0000 0000 8f81 764a 0000  PK..........vJ..
---
> 00000000: 504b 0304 0a00 0000 0000 9081 764a 0000  PK..........vJ..
3c3
< 00000020: 4b01 021e 030a 0000 0000 008f 8176 4a00  K............vJ.
---
> 00000020: 4b01 021e 030a 0000 0000 0090 8176 4a00  K............vJ.
```

But I don't understand the zip binary format well enough to interpret this in my head. Needless to say, extracting both these archives results in an identical file.

Anyone know why this is happening? The `-X` flag is clearly having *some* effect because if I omit it in the experiment above, the diff of the resulting zips is even more different than it is here.

I have only tested this on Linux, with an ext4 filesystem; I'm not sure if OS X or other filesystems would behave the same way.

Comment: According to the documentation, that position is clearly the original date/time of the compressed file. It may be that the indicator for not keeping the file date/time is in the relevant field in the central directory, and the local date/time is used for handling the Update functionality.

Comment: `(Note: don't do $ touch a/1 b/1 in a single command, since then the file creation timestamps might be identical and this experiment won't work)`....you got the answer....different metadata info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to pass the -X flag to zip, which causes it to ignore file attributes like the creation/modification time

What it ignores are *extra* attributes.

Standard attributes are not affected. These are things like filename, file type, modification date/time, CRC and uncompressed size.

Extra attributes are system specific extensions like Linux's UID, GID, atime and mtime in epoch time.

Other OS have other extensions for the attributes they care about, like Windows NT security descriptors or OS/2 specific ACLs.

The `-X` flag strips these extra attributes, leaving you with the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this clears it up. It's incredibly frustrating that you can't create reproducible artifacts with a utility as common as zip, but at least now I know :)